# Split a CSV file into multiple files and and give a unique name based on a Appname field. Fetch only account column in the newly created Appname-file

Tags: powershell

I have a query in PowerShell, I need to split a single CSV file into different files based on the appname and with only account information and ignore the rest of the columns. Please help me here to solve it from a PowerShell script.

[image: table]

[image: getting only the account name]

```
$InputFilePath = "E:\Test_csv\test.csv"
$SplitByColumnName = "AppName" #Enter ColumnName here on basis of which you want to split.

$data = Import-Csv $InputFilePath | Select -ExpandProperty $SplitByColumnName -Unique

$a = $data | select 

ForEach ($i in $a)
{  
  $FinalFileNamePath = "E:\Test_csv\" + $i + ".CSV" #This is where you would keep the splitted files.

  Import-Csv $InputFilePath | where {$_.$SplitByColumnName -eq $i } | Export-Csv $FinalFileNamePath -NoTypeInformation  
}
```

I tried the above code but how to get only the account name instead of all the columns?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your question. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Csv = @'
name,  account,  Appname, count, users, List
name1, account1,     123,     1,     2, abc
name1, account2,     123,     2,     3, z
name1, account3,     123,     3,     6, xc
name1, account4,     123,     5,     7, df
name1, account5,     123,     5,     8, rg
name1, account6,     123,     7,     0, sfg
name2, account1,     456,     1,     1, dfg
name3, account1,     789,     3,     7, rt
name3, account2,     789,     7,     1, ert
'@
```

**For what you tried:**
You will need to filter (`Where-Object`) upon the `Appname` and select (`Select-Object`) upon the `account` name. If you use appropriate variable names (rather than `$a` and `$i`), things might get clearer:
<sup>(Personally, I value variable names more than comments)</sup>

```
$SplitByColumnName = "AppName" # Enter ColumnName here on basis of which you want to split.

$data = ConvertFrom-Csv $Csv # = Import-Csv $InputFilePath
$AppNames = $Data | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $SplitByColumnName -Unique

ForEach ($Appname in $Appnames) {
  $FinalFileNamePath = "E:\Test_csv\" + $Appname + ".CSV" #This is where you would keep the splitted files.
  Import-Csv $InputFilePath |
    Where-Object Appname -eq $Appname |
    Select-Object Account |
    Export-Csv $FinalFileNamePath -NoTypeInformation  
}
```

[**Avoid wrapping cmdlet pipelines**](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations#avoid-wrapping-cmdlet-pipelines)
Note that wrapping cmdlets (as `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv`) in a loop is expensive as it (re)opens and closes the concerns files each cycle.
To avoid this in your case, you might use the steppable pipeline and create multiple output streams to fill the concerned exported `csv` files.

```
$Pipeline = @{}
ConvertFrom-Csv $Csv | # Import-Csv $InputFilePath |
ForEach-Object -Process {
    if (!$Pipeline.Contains($_.Appname)) {
        $Pipeline[$_.Appname] = {
            Select-Object Account | Export-CSV -NoType -Path "E:\Test_csv\$($_.Appname).CSV"  
        }.GetSteppablePipeline()
        $Pipeline[$_.Appname].Begin($True)
    }
    $Pipeline[$_.Appname].Process($_)
} -End {
    foreach ($Key in $Pipeline.Keys) { $Pipeline[$Key].End() }
}
```

For background and details, see: [Mastering the (steppable) pipeline](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/mastering-the-steppable-pipeline/)