# Foreach loop that creates ps-objects and write them into new separates arrays gets progressively slower

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

In my script i try to sepperate a csv that i imported into an array, into 11 different arrays. I do this by checking a id in each array object which decides into which new array the data should be transfered. I achieve this by creating new ps-objects whith the relevant informations and then adding them to the other arrays.

The source file i have is 700.000 lines long and the problem is that my foreach loop in which i sepperate the data gets progressively slower. I tested with 5000 lines and they were through in a few seconds, but with the complete Data set i had to cancel the execution of the script after 1:15h.

This is my script:

```
$Nest1 = @()
$Nest2 = @()
$Nest3 = @()
$Nest4 = @()
$Nest5 = @()
$Nest6 = @()
$Nest7 = @()
$Nest8 = @()
$Nest9 = @()
$Nest10 = @()
$Errornest = @()
$counter = 0

$Pfad = 'C:\Users\Measurements\Documents\Data.csv'
$Header = 'Type','Date','Time','Nestid','Value','goempty'

$Data = Import-Csv $pfad -Delimiter ";" -Header $Header

$Data = $Data | where-Object {$_.Value -ne "Waage antwortet nicht" -and $_.Date -ne ""} 

$total = $Data.count

Foreach ($Dat in $Data){
$counter ++
Write-Progress -Activity 'Processing Data' -PercentComplete (($counter / $total) * 100)

    if($Dat.Nestid -eq 1){
       $Nestobject = New-Object psobject
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Type' -Value $Dat.type
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Date' -Value $Dat.Date
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Time' -Value $Dat.Time
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Value' -Value $Dat.Value
       $Nest1 += $Nestobject
    }
    elseif($Dat.Nestid -eq 2){
       $Nestobject = New-Object psobject
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Type' -Value $Dat.type
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Date' -Value $Dat.Date
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Time' -Value $Dat.Time
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Value' -Value $Dat.Value
       $Nest2 += $Nestobject
    }
    elseif($Dat.Nestid -eq 3){       
       $Nestobject = New-Object psobject
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Type' -Value $Dat.type
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Date' -Value $Dat.Date
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Time' -Value $Dat.Time
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Value' -Value $Dat.Value
       $Nest3 += $Nestobject
    }
    elseif($Dat.Nestid -eq 4){
       $Nestobject = New-Object psobject
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Type' -Value $Dat.type
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Date' -Value $Dat.Date
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Time' -Value $Dat.Time
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Value' -Value $Dat.Value
       $Nest4 += $Nestobject
    }
    elseif($Dat.Nestid -eq 5){
       $Nestobject = New-Object psobject
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Type' -Value $Dat.type
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Date' -Value $Dat.Date
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Time' -Value $Dat.Time
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Value' -Value $Dat.Value
       $Nest5 += $Nestobject}
    elseif($Dat.Nestid -eq 6){
       $Nestobject = New-Object psobject
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Type' -Value $Dat.type
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Date' -Value $Dat.Date
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Time' -Value $Dat.Time
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Value' -Value $Dat.Value
       $Nest6 += $Nestobject}
    elseif($Dat.Nestid -eq 7){
       $Nestobject = New-Object psobject
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Type' -Value $Dat.type
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Date' -Value $Dat.Date
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Time' -Value $Dat.Time
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Value' -Value $Dat.Value
       $Nest7 += $Nestobject}
    elseif($Dat.Nestid -eq 8){      
       $Nestobject = New-Object psobject
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Type' -Value $Dat.type
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Date' -Value $Dat.Date
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Time' -Value $Dat.Time
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Value' -Value $Dat.Value
       $Nest8 += $Nestobject}
    elseif($Dat.Nestid -eq 9){       
       $Nestobject = New-Object psobject
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Type' -Value $Dat.type
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Date' -Value $Dat.Date
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Time' -Value $Dat.Time
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Value' -Value $Dat.Value
       $Nest9 += $Nestobject}
    elseif($Dat.Nestid -eq 10){       
       $Nestobject = New-Object psobject
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Type' -Value $Dat.type
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Date' -Value $Dat.Date
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Time' -Value $Dat.Time
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Value' -Value $Dat.Value
       $Nest10 += $Nestobject}
    else{       
       $Nestobject = New-Object psobject
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Type' -Value $Dat.type
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Date' -Value $Dat.Date
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Time' -Value $Dat.Time
       $Nestobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'Value' -Value $Dat.Value
       $Errornest += $Nestobject}
}
```

I already thought about writing a function for creating the accordig object, but i guess that would only bring better readability to the script and not really increase the performance.

Just in case the Data structure i have also is relevant, the source csv looks something like this:

```
I;17.07.2023;11:16:32;9;000734d9c1;
W;17.07.2023;11:16:31;7;120.79;g                   
W;17.07.2023;11:16:31;3;Waage antwortet nicht;
W;17.07.2023;11:16:32;4;5.08;g                   
W;17.07.2023;11:16:33;10;148.49;g                   
W;17.07.2023;11:16:32;2;49.91;g                   
W;17.07.2023;11:16:33;9;117.13;g                   
I;17.07.2023;11:16:33;9;000734d9c1;
I;17.07.2023;11:16:34;9;000734d9c1;
```

Comment: `+=` kills puppies

Comment: no poor puppies, why though?

Comment: It copies the array every time.  It's a common practice though.  I wonder if it was ever optimized in powershell 7.

Comment: As suggested by @js2010, [try to avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026) as it is ineffective).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, it's a very bad practice to paste examples as screenshots.
Why don't you use a design like:

```
$Nest1 = $Data | Where-Object {$_.Nestid -eq '1'} | Select Type, Date, Time, Value
```

This should work faster. But I think you first need to understand why 11 separate arrays are needed in the first place.

Comment: Wouldnt that be slower, since i would have to do this once for every new array, which would result in 11 times that i go through all the data? I will try this approach a little edited in the foreach line.

Comment: In this example **foreach** is not needed

Comment: i tried your approach and left the Errornest variable out for the first test run(since i didnt want to write a 2 line statement with -ne 1 and -ne 2 etc...), it was significantly faster with only about 15 minutes, thank you very much.

Comment: In this case, please mark the answer as the solution :)

Comment: @Trippin, a way to get around building *11 separate arrays* and potentially keeping 700.000 lines in memory is building 11 [Steppable Pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/mastering-the-steppable-pipeline/) based on your `$_.Nestid`. See also: [Split a CSV file into multiple files and and give a unique name based on a Appname field. Fetch only account column in the newly created Appname-file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76806435/1701026)

Answer (score 1):

First, some suggestions

1. Do not use Arrays but ArralyLists(`$VarName=[System.Collections.ArrayList]@()`)
   Because regular arrays get destroyed and rebuild from scratch each time they get modified, they are inefficient when one expects to change them often like in this case.
2. do not use for `Foreach ($Dat in $Data)` but `$Data | Foreach-Object`
3. do not use nested IFs but a SWITCH. It's pretty much made for this use-case.
   3.1. or use a variable IF like I did.
4. instead of creating each object THEN adding each property THEN adding it to the array, just add it in the array as you declare it

Second: I'm unsure if 10 different arrays is for the best.
I'd evaluate making one single array from the CSV and then using either the `.where({})` method of arrays and array lists.
es: `$Data.where({$_.NestId -eq 1})` would return the already-cooked PSCUtomObject collection of all the elements with nestId=1
Or piping it to `Where-Object` and\or `Select-Object` whenever necessary, but it's impossible to correctly evaluate without knowing the full scope an intent of the script

Last: have some code, it's on me. it SHOULD be a bit more efficient while also returning you the 10+1 arrays you wantedin your original script

```
    $Nest1 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    $Nest2 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    $Nest3 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    $Nest4 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    $Nest5 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    $Nest6 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    $Nest7 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    $Nest8 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    $Nest9 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    $Nest10 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

    $ErrorNest = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()


    $Pfad = 'C:\Users\Measurements\Documents\Data.csv'
    $Header = 'Type', 'Date', 'Time', 'Nestid', 'Value', 'goempty'

    $Data = Import-Csv $pfad -Delimiter ';' -Header $Header | Where-Object { $_.Value -ne 'Waage antwortet nicht' -and $_.Date -ne '' } | Select-Object 

    $total = $Data.count

    $data | ForEach-Object {
            
        Write-Progress -Activity 'Processing Data' -PercentComplete ((++$counter / $total) * 100)


        # this IF is very specific to this use-case
        if ($_.NestId -in 1..10) {
            $ArrayName = "Nest$_"
        }
        else {
            $ArrayName = 'ErrorNest'
        }
            
        # as alterantive, have a SWICTH, block-commented for reference
        # which is better if .NestId is not a simple progessive integer matching the Nest arrays names
        # (see line-commented examples at the bottom of the switch)
        <#
            switch ($_.NestId) {
                { 1 -eq $_ } { $ArrayName = "Nest$_"; Break }
                { 2 -eq $_ } { $ArrayName = "Nest$_"; Break }
                { 3 -eq $_ } { $ArrayName = "Nest$_"; Break }
                { 4 -eq $_ } { $ArrayName = "Nest$_"; Break }
                { 5 -eq $_ } { $ArrayName = "Nest$_"; Break }  
                { 6 -eq $_ } { $ArrayName = "Nest$_"; Break } 
                { 7 -eq $_ } { $ArrayName = "Nest$_"; Break }
                { 8 -eq $_ } { $ArrayName = "Nest$_"; Break }
                { 9 -eq $_ } { $ArrayName = "Nest$_"; Break }
                { 10 -eq $_ } { $ArrayName = "Nest$_"; Break }
                #{ 'Aldo' -eq $_} { $ArrayName="Mai"; break}
                #{ 'Giovanni' -eq $_} { $ArrayName="Dire"; break}
                #{ 'Franco' -eq $_ } { $ArrayName= "Ahiò"; Break}
                #{ 'Giacomo' -eq $_ } { $ArrayName="Gol"; Break}
                Default { $ArrayName = 'ErrorNest' }
            }
            #>

        # One variable action to do them all.
        # my preference is to use `$ArrayList.insert($Index, $Value)`, but regular `$ArrayList.add($Value)` works perfectly well
        # just note `.add` does return the integer of the index, you might want to catch it to avoid it showing in the stdOut.
            (Get-Variable -ValueOnly -Name "$ArrayName").insert(0,
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Type  = $_.Type
                Date  = $_.Date
                Time  = $_.Time
                Value = $_.Value
            }
        )


            
    }
```